# Need help understanding ungetc behavior used in conjuction with scanf 

Tags: c

I can't understand the behaviour of my program. It calls scanf, followed by ungetc and then printf.

I could not get the reason behind the output behaviour.
Here is the code.Would be great help if someone clarified the behaviour.

```
int main()
{
  int n=0;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  ungetc(n,stdin);
  printf("%d\n",n);
  return 0;
}
```

**Output in gcc compiler and linux platform:**
First if i give 90 then it waits for another number and after i give another number it prints 90.

Comment: At which point does it wait for another number? Why are you using ungetc?

Comment: It has nothing to do with `ungetc`, it's the scan format. Remove the `\n` and it prints immediately.

Comment: after i enter first say 90 it waits for another input.When i enter another number it prints 90.i was just experimenting with ungetc..just for learning purpose

Comment: oh..yes..when i removed \n it worked fine.but is using n after ungetc legal? is not n value sent back to buffer?

Comment: @vindhya no the variable remains untouched. `ungetc` receives the value of the variable, not the address and thus can't change the value.

Answer (score 2):

Ending your `scanf()` format with `\n` instructs `scanf()` to expect and eat all the whitespace it sees after your number. The reason that it looks like it's waiting for another input, is because it will read until it gets some *non-whitespace* character. Whatever you enter isn't actually read, but rather left on `stdin` for subsequent reads.

Answer (score 1):

The scan format

```
scanf("%d\n",&n);
```

consumes all whitespace that comes after the number you enter. Thus the scan is only finished after you have entered a non-whitespace character (and a newline to send the input to the programme). The `\n` doesn't demand a newline character specifically, it tells `scanf` to consume all following whitespace and ignore it.